# Text messages from contacts going to Unknown Senders

Tags: iphone, ios, contacts

Running iOS 12.1 on iPhone 6S and have messages from people in my contact list show up in Unknown Senders. These are people who text often and it happens randomly with 4 contacts and 3 groups. To “fix” it when it happens I have to restart the iPhone. It’s been going on for months and have done all iOS updates except 12.2. Any ideas on how to fix permanently?

Comment: Are these users in your contacts, or just previous people you've messaged

Comment: They are set up as contacts.

Comment: Any reason not to update to 12.2?

Comment: No. Just usually wait a week or 2 after a new release.